# Having problems with using TableForm to format a table

Tags: replacement, output-formatting, list-manipulation, numerical-value

I want to make a table of various values of the logistic curve given by `l[x_] := 1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha])))`.

In basic form, this is dead easy. However, I want to make some tweaks, and I can't persuade them to work.

(Apologies for images of table outputs - I don't know how to add the actual tables.)

1: Note that despite being wrapped in `N[...,4]`, the table evaluates to more than 4 decimal places for several values:

```
N[With[{k = 1}, TableForm[Table[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))), 
     {x, 1, 20}, {\[Alpha], 5, 15, 5}], TableHeadings -> 
     {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
         "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}, 
       {"\[Alpha]=5",  "10", "15"}}]], 4]
```

[image]

2: I want to use `l[x]` instead of the full expression. But this leads Mathematica to mostly ignore the stipulated value for `k`:

```
l[x_] := 1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))); 
N[With[{k = 1}, TableForm[Table[l[x], {x, 1, 20}, 
     {\[Alpha], 5, 15, 5}], TableHeadings -> 
     {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
         "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}, 
       {"\[Alpha]=5", "10", "15"}}]], 4]
```

[image]

3: I want the table to *display* `\[Tilde]0` or `\[Tilde]1` for values less than `0.0001` or greater than `0.9999` - but to *retain the actual numerical value* so I can perform further calulations on the table. I can change the values into text (though again this only works with the expression, not with `l[x]`), but of course, that means I can't then perform further caluations on them:

```
N[With[{k = 1}, TableForm[Table[If[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))) < 
         0.0001, Text["\[Tilde]0"], 
 If[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))) > 
           0.9999, Text["\[Tilde]1"], 
  1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha])))]], 
     {x, 1, 20}, {\[Alpha], 5, 15, 5}], TableHeadings -> 
     {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
         "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}, 
       {"\[Alpha]=5", "10", "15"}}]], 4]
```

[image]

4: I would like to put all output values of `0.5` in bold. But Mathematica seems to ignore the `/.` command:

```
N[With[{k = 1}, TableForm[Table[If[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))) < 
           0.0001, Text["\[Tilde]0"], 
  If[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))) > 
             0.9999, Text["\[Tilde]1"], 
   1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha])))]], 
       {x, 1, 20}, {\[Alpha], 5, 15, 5}], TableHeadings -> 
       {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", 
           "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
           "20"}, {"\[Alpha]=5", "10", "15"}}]], 4] /. 0.5 -> Style[0.5, Bold]
```

[image]

I'd very much appreciate suggestions to fix all four of these issues.

Comment: Images of output are fine, especially in cases like this; it's images of input that make it hard to provide help.

Comment: I find it strange you accepted my answer but didn't think it worth an up-vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solves all your problems.

```
l[x_, k_, α_] := 1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - α)));
table =
  Module[{boldVal, lhsLbls, tbl, tblForm, boldPos, zeroPos, onePos},
    boldVal = .5;
    lhsLbls = ToString /@ Range[20];
    lhsLbls[[1]] = "x=1";
    tbl = Table[With[{k = 1}, N[l[x, k, α], 4]], {x, 1, 20}, {α, 5, 15, 5}];
    tblForm = TableForm[tbl, TableHeadings -> {lhsLbls, {"α=5", "10", "15"}}];
    boldPos = Position[tblForm, u_?(# == boldVal &)];
    zeroPos = Position[tblForm, u_?(# < .0001 &)];
    onePos = Position[tblForm, u_?(1 - Rationalize[#] < 1/10000 &)];
    Print[
      MapAt[
        "∼1" &,
        MapAt[
          "∼0" &, 
          MapAt[Style[#, Bold] &, tblForm, boldPos], 
          zeroPos],
        onePos]];
    tbl]
```

[image: table]

> ```
> {{0.01799, 0.0001234, 8.315*10^-7}, {0.04743, 0.0003354, 2.260*10^-6}, 
>  {0.1192, 0.0009111, 6.144*10^-6}, {0.2689, 0.002473, 0.00001670}, 
>  {0.5000, 0.006693, 0.00004540}, {0.7311, 0.01799, 0.0001234}, 
>  {0.8808, 0.04743, 0.0003354}, {0.9526, 0.1192, 0.0009111}, 
>  {0.9820, 0.2689, 0.002473}, {0.9933, 0.5000, 0.006693}, 
>  {0.9975, 0.7311, 0.01799}, {0.9991, 0.8808, 0.04743}, 
>  {0.9997, 0.9526, 0.1192}, {0.9999, 0.9820, 0.2689}, 
>  {1.000, 0.9933, 0.5000}, {1.000, 0.9975, 0.7311}, 
>  {1.000, 0.9991, 0.8808}, {1.000, 0.9997, 0.9526}, 
>  {1.000, 0.9999, 0.9820}, {1.000, 1.000, 0.9933}}
> ```

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question:

`N` is really for controlling the precision of numerical calculations and in your code is, as intended, providing 4-digits of precision, or four *significant figures* if you want to put it that way.

For controlling the presentation of numbers there are a number of functions, such as `NumberForm`, `DecimalForm`, *etc*.  We might modify your

```
N[With[{k = 1}, TableForm[Table[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))), 
     {x, 1, 20}, {\[Alpha], 5, 15, 5}], TableHeadings -> 
     {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", 
         "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20"}, 
       {"\[Alpha]=5",  "10", "15"}}]], 4]
```

to

```
DecimalForm[
 N[With[{k = 1}, 
   TableForm[
    Table[1/(1 + E^((-k)*(x - \[Alpha]))), {x, 1, 20}, {\[Alpha], 5, 
      15, 5}], 
    TableHeadings -> {{"x=1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", 
       "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", 
       "20"}, {"\[Alpha]=5", "10", "15"}}]]], {4, 4}]
```

Note that I've dropped the argument (`4`) to `N` and provided the argument `{4,4}` to `DecimalForm`.

I expect that the answers to your other questions can also be found by separating the ideas of precision and presentation.  If I have time and the inclination I'll have a closer look later.

Comment: Thank you @High Performance Mark. this also answers my 4th question, where `/.` now works. Questions 2 and 3 will need more input; I hope you find you have more time!